# redis set value if key exist and not set if not exist

Tags: php, redis

I want to ensure that the key must be exist when I using `set` to set a value

the fake code with PHP:

```
    $expired_at = strtotime(date('Y-m-d')) + 24 * 3600;
    $key = "store_of_today";
    $left = $redis->get($key);
    if ($left === null) {
        $redis->set($key, 100);
        $redis->expireat($key, $expired_at);
        $left = 100;
    }

    // something run ...

    // here, I must ensure that the key is exist
    // for example, I got the value by using $redis->get($key)  at 23:59:59:999;
    // then the code run over 1ms, and now is 00:00:00:015 (run 16ms here)
    // the key is expired, so I can't set data to redis
    // even though I used $redis->exist($key) to check the key is exist or not,
    // but this code still need time to run, so I can't ensure the key is exist
    $redis->set($key, $new_left);
```

I know the redis has `setnx`, It seems like not some funciton like `setifexist`

Comment: `SET key value XX`

Answer (score 0):

After one years later, I found a way to figure out this with LUA script

```php
$get_lua = <<<LUA
local key = KEYS[1]
local expireAt = ARGV[1]

local value = redis.call('GET', key)
if value == false then
    redis.call('SET', key, 100)
    redis.call('EXPIREAT', key, expireAt)
    value = 100
end

return value
LUA;


$set_lua = <<<LUA
local key = KEYS[1]
local value = ARGV[1]
local expireAt = ARGV[2]

redis.call('SET', key, value)
redis.call('EXPIREAT', key, expireAt)
LUA;

$redis = new Redis();

$expired_at = strtotime(date('Y-m-d')) + 864000; // end of today
$key = "store_of_today";
$left = $redis->eval($get_lua, [$key, $expired_at], 1);

// code

$redis->eval($set_lua, [$key, $new_left, $expired_at], 1);
```

The redis ensure that a lua script is an atomic operation, so the `$set_lua` will always set a value and then set an `expireAt` on the key in once atomic operation, and if `expireAt` is a past timestamp, the key will be invalid.